# Kivy Refractoring

Tags: python, kivy

I have a very simple app ive been working on for work that ive written in python using Tkinter for the GUI. I've started rewriting it for Kivy to make it easier to compile for different platforms.  The code below is what i have so far. its a simple text entry and search button. but i'm building it out in my base class. I instead want to build these query controls in another class and then return them through the base class so that i can start on the right path from the start.

```
from kivy.app import App 
from kivy.uix.label import Label 
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput 
from kivy.uix.button import Button 
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.anchorlayout import AnchorLayout



class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):
        controls = AnchorLayout(anchor_x='left', anchor_y='top')
        box = BoxLayout()


        upc_l = Label(text='UPC:', font_size=40, size_hint_y=None, 
                      size_hint_x=None, height=50, width=100,)
        entry = TextInput(font_size=40, size_hint_y=None, size_hint_x=None, 
                          height=50, width=350)
        search_b = Button(text='Search', font_size=40, size_hint_y=None,       
                          size_hint_x=None, height=50, width=200)


        controls.add_widget(box)
        box.add_widget(upc_l)
        box.add_widget(entry)
        box.add_widget(search_b)


        return controls




if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

I want to refractor it like this:

```
from kivy.app import App 
from kivy.uix.label import Label 
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput 
from kivy.uix.button import Button 
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.anchorlayout import AnchorLayout


class Query():

    <whatever needs to go here...>


class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return Query()




if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

Comment: The term is "refactor", not "refractor"! Still, your question is very open-ended...

Comment: Hey at least i learned something from this post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.anchorlayout import AnchorLayout


class Query(AnchorLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Query, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.anchor_x = 'left'
        self.anchor_y='top'

        box = BoxLayout()

        upc_l = Label(text='UPC:', font_size=40, size_hint_y=None,
                      size_hint_x=None, height=50, width=100,)
        entry = TextInput(font_size=40, size_hint_y=None, size_hint_x=None,
                          height=50, width=350)
        search_b = Button(text='Search', font_size=40, size_hint_y=None,
                          size_hint_x=None, height=50, width=200)

        box.add_widget(upc_l)
        box.add_widget(entry)
        box.add_widget(search_b)
        self.add_widget(box)


class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return Query()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

Answer (score 2):

This is not a question.

Even if you want help with some aspect, you should explain what your problem is, what you have tried, and what went wrong.

For some general advice, you should use kv language to define your widget trees, it will make things simpler and easier.

Comment: I'm basically asking how do i go from the original code to having it structured like the example in the second bit of code. But nevermind i'll just read up on the kivy documentation.

Answer (score 1):

I highly suggest you watch through the 'crash course' video series. It's very helpful and will get you up to speed on using the kv language and python and the interaction between the two. Check them out [here](http://inclem.net/pages/kivy-crash-course/).